# Select tag not preselecting a value

Tags: jsp, select, struts2

I have Struts2 select tag in my jsp as :

```
<s:iterator value="data.members" status="rowstatus">
    <s:select id="Ct%{#rowstatus.index}" name="data.members[%{#rowstatus.index}].extData.carrierKey" headerKey="-1" headerValue="" list="carrier"
              onchange="javascript:autoTab(event,this,%{#rowstatus.index},false);">                                         
    </s:select>
</s:iterator
```

Now this `carrier` is a Map at back end which gets populated in this select tag. The carrier is populated as follows :

```
carrier = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
carrier.put(1,"LIC");
carrier.put(2, "Bajaj");
```

Now suppose jsp is displayed. I choose LIC in select tag and submit the form. Suppose some validation error occurs. I debugged the application and found that the value of variable `"data.members[%{#rowstatus.index}].extData.carrierKey"` in action class is 1. But its value is not populated on jsp.

I don't understand , why is the value not populating, if `data.members[%{#rowstatus.index}].extData.carrierKey` is set with value. According to me, if its value is 1, then select tag must show LIC.

Comment: The iterator tag is not required, so you can try without it. Also it's not clear what do you mean by preselecting a value.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by `name="data.members[%{#rowstatus.index}].extData.carrierKey"`? is `...extData.carrierKey` the value you want to be default selected?

Comment: Sorry. There was something on javascript that was clearing the value before it could be populated in the tag. Well, thanks everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and works fine to me.

JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head><title>Stack Overflow</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>Stack Overflow</h1>

    <s:form action="stackoverflow"  method="POST">
        <s:iterator value="data.members" status="rowstatus">

           <s:select    id="Ct%{#rowstatus.index}"
                    name="data.members[%{#rowstatus.index}].extData.carrierKey" 
                    headerKey="-1" 
                    headerValue="" 
                    list="carrier"
                    onchange="javascript:autoTab(event,this,%{#rowstatus.index},false);"
                    >                                         
            </s:select>

        </s:iterator>
        <br/>
        <s:submit value="Submit!" method="save" />
    </s:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function autoTab(ev, current,nextElementIndex, varBool){
            document.getElementById("stackoverflow").elements[nextElementIndex].focus();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Action:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2.actions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.tutorialspoint.struts2.entities.ObjectData;
import com.tutorialspoint.struts2.entities.ObjectMember;

public class StackOverflowAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9053634696133432054L;

    private Map<Integer, String> carrier;
    private ObjectData data;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return MyAction.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String save()  throws Exception {
        return MyAction.SUCCESS;
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> getCarrier() {
        if(this.carrier == null) {
            this.carrier = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            this.carrier.put(1,"LIC");
            this.carrier.put(2, "Bajaj");
        }
        return carrier;
    }

    public ObjectData getData() {
        if(this.data == null) {
            this.data = new ObjectData();
            ObjectMember member1 = new ObjectMember();
            member1.getExtData().setCarrierKey("");
            ObjectMember member2 = new ObjectMember();
            member2.getExtData().setCarrierKey("");
            this.data.getMembers().add(member1);
            this.data.getMembers().add(member2);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
    <package name="stackoverflow" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <action name="stackoverflow" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.actions.StackOverflowAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/jsp/stackoverflow/test.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```